# Calculate the power of e (e^x), why n = 999?

Tags: c

Well, I was looking on the net for a code to calculate the power of e (e^x) and found a few good codes for that. Then I found the following code and just wants to know what the n = 999 part and n <= 100 part are supposed to do? I mean.. why n <= 100? why n = 999?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ACCURACY 0.0001

int main() {
   int n, count;
   float x, term, sum;

   printf("\nEnter value of x :");
   scanf("%f", &x);

   n = term = sum = count = 1;

   while (n <= 100) {
      term = term * x / n;
      sum = sum + term;
      count = count + 1;

      if (term < ACCURACY)
         n = 999;
      else
         n = n + 1;
   }

   printf("\nTerms = %d Sum = %f", count, sum);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will imply infinity.

Comment: n=999 is intended to break the loop.

Comment: it works as while loop termination logic, n= 101 also does the same

Comment: Stop using `float` unless you have constraints. Use `double`. Note that `ACCURACY` is of type `double` anyway.

Comment: Well, if you've found "good codes", why are you showing *this* one? What happens to this code when you input `-1`?

Comment: Mainly because i found some parts of this specific code confusing and wanted answers. And about the -1 thing (thank you for pointing that out by the way) it doesn't give an accurate result :/

Comment: Not all code you find will be high-quality. If the code is difficult to understand *and* doesn't have comments, it is unlikely to be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a sum of terms in a series. 
The term < ACCURACY test just looks to see if the desired accuracy was reached. If not, it goes to the next term in the series. If yes, n = 999 just makes the loop end. You could put there break; with the same result.